# signinwithemail link error using react-native, Firebase and expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Error encountered
This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.
I am trying to use signin with email link in firebase and React Apllication build using EXPO
when i run this code i get the email link but when i click on that link i get this error
My code is

```
  const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: ` https://servy-a8ef2.firebaseapp.com`,
    handleCodeInApp: true,
  };
  await firebase
    .auth()
    .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
    .then(function () {
     
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
    });
```

Comment: I am using web sdk in firebase with expo. In short how to i redirect to my app. because i can successfully send link to email

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if it’s still relevant, I had the same error. Maybe for someone it will be useful.

First of all, check your link, there is a space before https, firebase may encode it as "%20https..." That’s why it does not work. And check your quotes as well, the back quotes can be encoded differently.

I had problem with an environmental variable, i put the value with quotes, that google encoded as  "%27http......%27". So that was my error.